# SWF has higher framerate than specified in the compiler arguments

Tags: actionscript-3, ant, frame-rate, fdt

I compile a SWF with ANT using FDT. In the compiler arguments I am setting default-frame-rate to 30. When I run the SWF, the stage.framerate property is 30 (which is correct), but as the Stats util from mrdoob shows, the SWF runs way faster – up to 52 fps.

So it seems the compiler argument default-frame-rate is applied, still the events are fired at a higher rate. How can that be?

These are the compiler arguments:

```
compilerarguments="-target-player=10 -swf-version=10 -default-frame-rate 30 -default-background-color=0x000000"
```

Comment: you aren't running your SWF through a shell swf, right? the player's framerate is set by the root SWF, and framerates do not vary within the same FlashPlayer instance.

Comment: No, I am not. It is only one SWF. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: StatsUtil might be off in its calculations if it runs on Timer. Flash's clock is not accurate.

Comment: No, I can clearly see that all animations triggered by ENTER_FRAME are running faster than they should.

Comment: just in case - is there a `[SWF]` metatag with the `frameRate` argument in the document class?

Comment: You realize how old this question is? ;) IIRC I used the SWF metatag back then.

Answer (score 0):

Unless gthmb is correct, something, somewhere is setting stage.frameRate to another (higher) value.

Comment: That was my thought at first, but for testing I logged the stage.frameRate every frame of the animation, and it still stated 30fps. I solved it back then by using a timer, not so pretty, but I had to come up with a solution quickly.